# Развернуть окно по высоте

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно (форма). Начиная с win7 (может и висты) есть такая функция как развернуть окно по высоте. Т.е. в итоге форма останется той же ширины, но займет максимально дозволенные размеры по высоте.

Как развернуть форму программно по высоте, т.е. поставить в 0-ую позицию по Y и дать ему максимальную высоту (до пуска)? Есть ли специальная функция? Собственно проблема высоту узнать. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

Вам нужно для начала выяснить необходимую высоту. Она, разумеется, зависит от того, на каком мониторе ваше окно. Для главного монитора высоту можно получить просто как [`SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (у `SystemParameters` ещё много полезных свойств, посмотрите, может быть пригодятся). В этом случае вам придётся обеспечить запуск приложения на главном мониторе.

Или вы можете обойти все мониторы (или если ваше окно уже на экране, выяснить, на каком оно мониторе), как советуют [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/254197/276994) (через функциональность WinForms `Screen.FromHandle` или [`Screen.AllScreens`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056727/276994)) и выяснить высоту нужного монитора.

Отлично, у нас есть высота. Теперь есть две стратегии: «прикрепить» окно (как в maximize-режиме) или разрешить изменять размеры (как в Vista/Windows 7). Для второго варианта вы просто устанавливаете Y-позицию в 0 и высоту в нужное значение (возможно, надо будет подправить ещё и X, чтобы окно полностью переместилось на выбранный монитор). Если вы хотите прикрепить, попробуйте установить `Binding` на манер того, как описано [здесь](http://programminghacks.net/2009/11/05/maximize-wpf-window-only-vertically-or-horizontally/). (Этот код следит за изменениями размера окна и обновляет высоту автоматически.)

Comment: Спасибо :) помогло. Воспользовался [SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight][1]

> Получает высоту (в точках) клиентской области для полноэкранного окна на основном мониторе.

Решил не возиться с несколькими экранами )


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.systemparameters.fullprimaryscreenheight(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Пожалуйста!